# Gaussian process regressions estimates of confidence intervals

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics, regression, gaussian, gpflow

This may be an odd question, but when Gaussian process regressions see a bunch of noisy data without much of a signal, what do they do? Below I take a bunch of noisy data and run two different implementations of GPR and they both produce super tiny confidence intervals. Is there a good reason as to why this is the case? My intuition is telling me the confidence intervals should be larger. Are GPR's really that confident in their estimate of the mean? Additionally, is there an appropriate way to pad the variance estimates aside from adding a white noise kernel?

```
import numpy as np
import gpflow as gpflow
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import DotProduct, WhiteKernel, Matern, RBF

## some data
X1 = np.array([ 2.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  7.,  7.,  7.,
        8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9., 10., 11., 11., 12.,
       12., 12., 13., 13., 14., 14., 15., 15., 15., 16.])

Y1  = np.array([-0.70007257, -0.69388464, -0.63062014, -0.72834303, -0.67526754,
        1.00259286, -0.96141351, -0.08295884,  1.0727982 , -2.29816347,
       -0.61594418,  1.13696593, -2.18716473, -0.35037363,  1.96273672,
        1.31621059, -1.88566144,  1.80466116, -0.79665828,  2.40720146,
        1.83116473, -1.67224082, -0.96766061, -0.67430408,  1.79624005,
       -1.41192248,  1.01754167,  0.37327703, -1.1195072 ,  0.71855107,
       -1.16906878,  0.99336417,  1.12563488, -0.36836713,  0.12574823,
        0.23294988])

## gpflow
model = gpflow.models.GPR(X=X1[:,None],
                         Y= Y1[:,None], kern=gpflow.kernels.RBF(1))

gpflow.train.ScipyOptimizer().minimize(model)

## scikit
kernel = RBF()
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel,
        random_state=0).fit(X= X1[:,None], y= Y1[:, None])

# plot function
def plot(m,  gpflow =True):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
    xtest = np.linspace(np.min(X1),np.max(X1), 20)[:,None]
    line, = plt.plot(X1, Y1, 'x', mew=2)

    if gpflow:
        mu, var = m.predict_f(np.hstack((xtest, np.zeros_like(xtest))))

        plt.plot(xtest, mu, color="green", lw=2, label="GPflow")
        plt.fill_between(xtest[:, 0], 
                         (mu - 2*np.sqrt(var))[:, 0], 
                         (mu + 2*np.sqrt(var))[:, 0], 
                         color="lightgreen", alpha=0.4)
    else:   
        mu, se = m.predict(xtest, return_std=True)

        plt.plot(xtest, mu, color="red", lw=2, label="Scipy")
        plt.fill_between(xtest[:, 0], 
                         (mu - 2*se)[:, 0], 
                         (mu + 2*se)[:, 0], 
                         color="red", alpha=0.4)


    plt.legend()
```

[image: Gpflow estimates]

[[image: Scipy estimates[2]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often helpful to look at the actual optimized values of your model hyperparameters - in this case noise variance, kernel variance and kernel lengthscale:

```
                             class           ...                             value
GPR/kern/lengthscales    Parameter           ...                3.7149993613788737
GPR/kern/variance        Parameter           ...            2.0572871322469534e-06
GPR/likelihood/variance  Parameter           ...                1.5461369937869296
```

So the GP explains everything away as noise (in this case, the actual value of the lengthscales is pretty arbitrary, and it's the tiny kernel variance that's important). (If you use predict_y instead of predict_f you should get a confidence interval that covers most of the observations.) The "RBF" (I prefer squared exponential - every stationary kernel describes radial basis functions...) kernel makes very strong smoothness assumptions on the functions in your prior (and also this only uses maximum likelihood point estimates for the hyperparameters), and so in that sense there's not much flexibility - and once you've explained all the data away, the GP is in some sense "saying" that there is no signal, therefore you get the prior back - which has zero mean. Does this help a bit ?

Comment: yeah, that helps and well I kind of thought that the likelihood variance was sucking up everything. I am hesitant of just using predict_y instead of predict_f as that is a different interpretation, right? Second questions would be is there anyway to avoid this (i.e. best practices) to ensure that the GPR actually picks up a signal (e.g. constraining the likelihood variance)?

Comment: @rprog yes, predict_y and predict_f have very different interpretations - in this case, they have the same mean (though that needn't be the case, it's only when your likelihood distribution is symmetric), and the variance of predict_f is the uncertainty in this mean, whereas the variance returned by predict_y describes the uncertainty of the data (in this case, predict_f variance + likelihood (noise) variance). Depends on what you want. For non-Gaussian likelihoods, it might be more sensible to consider quantiles of your distribution than just mean and var (which may be ill-defined).

Comment: @rprog second question: well, what's the signal that you would expect to find in this toy example ? If you want to describe these datapoints with infinitely differentiable functions, then I would argue a flat line does make a lot of sense! If you use a different kernel, you'll get different answers - e.g. compare the results you get for Matern12 (continuous non-differentiable functions), Matern32 (once differentiable), Matern52 (twice differentiable)...

Comment: I see your point and your rationale and I'm kind of forced to accept it, but I don't like accepting it. matern12, 32, and 52 all give me the same answer, which makes me rethink my decision to use GPR in the first place.

Comment: I do think a GP is a very useful approach to modelling this kind of data while avoiding overfitting & getting reasonable confidence intervals out of it. However, it does require you to think about what you want to get out. To start with, what would be the signal you (as a human) would draw in there? And what would your confidence intervals on that be?

Another thought: maybe Gaussian noise isn't the right assumption here - you could try, for example, a Student's-T likelihood to account for outliers. This won't work with plain GPR though, you'd need a VGP model for example, or do MCMC.